# GWT client "throws Exception" cause compling problem

Tags: gwt, opencalais

I try to use get result from a api called j-calais, and then out put the result on a web page, i write all the code in client, but it cant compile right, dont know why??? please help. the source code like below:

there is no obvious error arise, but it cant be compile successfully..... thanks a lot:

public void onModuleLoad() {
    // Create table for stock data.
    stocksFlexTable.setText(0, 0, "Type");
    stocksFlexTable.setText(0, 1, "Name");

```
// Assemble Add Stock panel.
addPanel.add(newSymbolTextBox);
addPanel.add(addStockButton);

// Assemble Main panel.
mainPanel.add(stocksFlexTable);
mainPanel.add(addPanel);
mainPanel.add(lastUpdatedLabel);

// Associate the Main panel with the HTML host page.
RootPanel.get("stockList").add(mainPanel);

// Move cursor focus to the input box.
newSymbolTextBox.setFocus(true);
```

// Listen for mouse events on the Add button.
    addStockButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
      public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

```
                        try {
                            addStock();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

  }
});
// Listen for keyboard events in the input box.
newSymbolTextBox.addKeyPressHandler(new KeyPressHandler() {
  public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {
    if (event.getCharCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER) {  
            try {
                addStock();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
  }
  }
});
```

}

```
private void addStock() throws Exception {
  final String url_s = newSymbolTextBox.getText().toUpperCase().trim();
  newSymbolTextBox.setFocus(true);
  newSymbolTextBox.setText("");
  int row = stocksFlexTable.getRowCount();


  CalaisClient client = new CalaisRestClient("ysw5rx69jkvdnzqf6sgjduqj");
    System.out.print("read success...\n");
     URL url = new URL(url_s);    
     CalaisResponse response = client.analyze(url);         
        for (CalaisObject entity : response.getEntities()) {
            System.out.println(entity.getField("_type") + ":" 
                               + entity.getField("name"));
            stocks.add(entity.getField("_type"));
            stocksFlexTable.setText(row, 0, entity.getField("_type"));
            stocksFlexTable.setText(row, 1, entity.getField("name"));
          }

        for (CalaisObject topic : response.getTopics()) {
            System.out.println(topic.getField("categoryName"));
          }
```

}

}

Comment: Please add the error you get that will help answering your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GWT only handles **unchecked exceptions** so you can throw **Runtime Exceptions**

or write your own Exception that **extends** from Runtime Exception then it will not cause any compile time problem

```
void f() throws NullPointerException // will not cause any problem because it is Runtime exception so unchecked

void f() throws IllegalAccessException // it is checked exception so there will be problem at compile time
```